# Shipping method is coming in the response of estimate-shipping-methods in the network console in Magento 2.4.0 ver

Tags: magento, magento2

I have completely integrated aramex sipping extension complete as I see It's working too.

in the request console it's working fine you can see in below image.

[image]

but the issue is it's not showing shipping method in the list like below screenshot.

[image]

how do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found it from where it is happening. because of other extension is not showing.

I disabled all module except this shipping method module and checked one by one by enabling and I found which module are conflicting with this shipping method.